# bitwise right shift large number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, clang

Why do I not get the correct answer if I do like this:

```
long long number = 5500000000000000; // 16 digit number - 53bit
long long temp_number = 0;

temp_number = number >> 50;

printf("%d", temp_number);
```

Answer will be: 4

That is not correct, I want it to show 5.

Kind regards

Comment: What makes you believe the answer should be 5 ?

Comment: if i shift fiftie times right the binary number: 10011100010100011100010001010010000111100000000000000..... err I rest my case and remove the question!

Comment: Just tried it on my trusty Windows 7 Programmer Calculator and I get 4...

Comment: look at my binarys and you will get the answer why you get it as a 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bit pattern of that number is:

```
10011100010100011100010001010010000111100000000000000
```

When shifting right 50 places, you are essentially discarding the 50 least significant bits, so you are left with:

```
100
```

Which,coincidentally, is 4.

Answer (score 4):

```
5500000000000000 = 0000 0000 0001 0011 1000 1010 0011 1000 1000 1010 0100 0011 1100 0000 0000 0000
```

When you shift by 50 you get:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 = 4
```

There is no way to make it 5 only by shifting right.